# Python imaplib удаление писем

Tags: python, imap, email

Здравствуйте. Необходимо иметь возможность помечать письма как удаленные и просматривать удаленные письма.
Удалить можно так:

```
typ, data = M.search(None, 'ALL')
for num in data[0].split():
M.store(num, '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
M.expunge()
```

Но как их потом прочитать?

Answer (score 1):

Перед
    M.store(num, '+FLAGS', '\Deleted')

Сообщение нужно скопировать в Trash.
Потом их можно читать из  Trash.